# Can the Tasks API 2.0 allow execution of entries in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

As part of the [Cake](http://cakebuild.net) integration with VSCode, [this](http://cakebuild.net/blog/2016/09/debug-cake-vscode) is how we recommend people configure the ability to debug a *.cake file.

With the new Task API, is it possible to automatically add a Task into the VSCode instance to allow launching of the debugger?  Or would this always be something that would have to exist within the launch.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported a debugger connection requires a launch.json.

The coreclr debugger can simplify this by contributing a [launch configuration snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesdebuggers) that supports to create a launch config for debugging a *.cake file. 
For example, the node-debugger adapter contributes launch configuration snippet to create a launch config for [debugging a gulp task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug/blob/master/package.json#L244).

Comment: Oooo, that sounds like exactly what we need! Will definitely give this a try, and report back, thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this does exactly what I want :-) https://github.com/cake-build/cake-vscode/issues/27#issuecomment-316193331